# Apache Virtual Host for Main Domain Returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: apache, ssl, dns, virtualhost, http-status-code-400

My webserver hosts a main domain and a subdomain with Apache2, with the main being just a placeholder HTML page, and the subdomain being a python/django application.

I am facing an interesting problem that sprung up sometime after adding the A record to my DNS settings (in GoDaddy) to enable the subdomain and the associated Apache VirtualHost.

The problem is that navigating to my subdomain, `www.testing.mysite.com`, works, but the main domain, `www.mysite.com`, results in a 400 Bad Request error. Both the main and the subdomains worked initially.

SSL has been enabled on both the main and the subdomain VirtualHosts with Let's Encrypt with http to https redirection, and worked fine for both until the problem sprang up suddenly.

The GoDaddy records look like the following

```
Type    Name       Value            TTL
a       @          xx.xx.xxx.xxx    600 seconds
a       admin      xx.xx.xxx.xxx    1 Hour
a       staging    xx.xx.xxx.xxx    1 Hour
a       testing    xx.xx.xxx.xxx    1 Hour
cname   www        @                1 Hour
```

The Apache configuration for the main domain looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public_html
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public_html
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache configuration for the subdomain looks as follows:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite_demo python-path=/var/www/mysite-testing
WSGIProcessGroup mysite_demo
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite-testing/mysite_demo/wsgi.py

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite-testing
    ServerAlias www.testing.mysite.com
    ServerName testing.mysite.com

    Alias /static /var/www/mysite-testing/static
    <Directory /var/www/mysite-testing/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite-testing/mysite_demo>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =testing.mysite.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.testing.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite-testing
    ServerAlias www.testing.mysite.com
    ServerName testing.mysite.com

    Alias /static /var/www/mysite-testing/static
    <Directory /var/www/mysite-testing/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite-testing/mysite_demo>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.mysite.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.mysite.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Would appreciate any help in figuring this out. Thank you.

Comment: You have both testing.mysite.com and mysite.com pointing to the same IP, which is all hosted on the single Apache server right?  Apache matches the VirtualHosts from top to bottom.  So in your configuration you should put the VH for testing.mysite.com before the one for mysite.com.  Put the more specific name first, then the more generic one.  Now for your https problem, that could be anything.  You did not show configuration, we can't help.

Comment: For your SSL, check that all valid names are put in the alternate names of your certificate.  Otherwise you will need many certificates!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the SSL part of the VirtualHost configuration as well. The configurations are in two files: `mysite.conf` and `mysite_demo.conf` for mysite.com and testing.mysite.com respectively. I have two different SSL certificates for the VHs. Does it help to have all of the VirutalHost configurations in one file with the more specific handled first, and the generic thereafter, as you mentioned?